# Is the following integral convergent

Tags: calculus

does anyone know whether the integral from 0 to infinity of ln(x^2)/e^(x^2) is convergent or divergent using the comparison theorem.

This was my reasoning but I’m not very sure on it:

Let g(x)= ln(x^2)/e^(x^2)

I broke the integral into two parts:

1) integral of g(x) from 0 to 2 - clearly this is a definite integral 
2) integral of g(x) from 2 to infinity

Focusing on 2), i then made ln(x^2)=2ln(x) so that I could bring the two out of the integral for simplicity.

I then observed that for all x belonging to the interval [2,infinity), that x^2 is greater than x, implying that 1/e^x is greater than 1/e^(x^2).

Then I observed that 1/e^x>ln(x)/e^(x^2). However how do I show this via inequalities/logic.

I then left f(x)= 1/e^x which is convergent integral meaning that ln(x^2)/e^(x^2) is convergent by comparison theorem

I am unsure is this is legitimate reasoning .. what is your reasoning?

Thanks - I have spent a whole day on this... I just can’t get anywhere with it

Answer (score 2):

On $(0,1)$ you might use $|\ln(x)| < 1/x^{1/2}$ and $|e^{-x^2}| \le 1$.

On $(1, \infty)$ you might use $|\ln(x)| < x < 2 e^{x/2}$ and $e^{-x^2} < e^{-x}$.